# agregar expresiones regulares en un array o objetos

Tags: array

quiero mostrar cuantas palabras hay aunque separare con mas espacios en intermedios, hay 5 palabras y quiero que me muestre 5 palabras aunque separe en medio de ellas. se que con expresiones regulares esto es posible pero no las comprendo del todo.

```html
let array=" hola estudio  javascript   para mejorar  "; //  5 palabras
array=array.trim();
array=regex.replace(array,@/\s/," ");  // expresion regular
let words=array.split(" ");
console.log("tiene: "+words.length+" palabras");
```

Answer (score 0):

Como bien hiciste, primero borra los espacios en blanco al inicio y al final con la función `.trim()`.

```
array = array.trim();
```

Posteriormente, separa las palabras cortando en la cadena por donde hayan 1 o más espacios en blanco `/\s+/`:

```
let words = array.split(/\s+/);
```

Puedes encadenar las dos sentencias en una sola:

```
let words = array.trim().split(/\s+/);
```

Finalmente tu código completo quedaría:

```js
let array = " hola estudio  javascript   para mejorar  "; //  5 palabras
let words = array.trim().split(/\s+/);
console.log("tiene: " + words.length + " palabras");
```